# Is there an MS Word version that supports HTML5 clipboard

Tags: java, html, ms-word, clipboard

ALL,

I believe that my question belong in SO. If someone feel otherwise, please comment.

My company has an application written in Java and it was working fine since it was working with Java 1.6. Recently we were tasked to upgrade the Java to 1.8 and we hit an interesting bug.

Whenever we try to copy formatted text from MS Word our code keep the font style (bold, italic, underline), but forget the size, coloring and font type. It's been suggested that since Java 1.8 has been rewritten to use HTML5, the parsing routines are not recognizing the stuff they suppose to.

Now unfortunately our test environment is still running MS Word 2007, which sure enough does not support HTML5. Our dev machines are running MS Word 2012, which probably does.

Now my question is: When Word performs Cut/Copy operation, is Clipboard saves the text as HTML5 or it is being saved as an old HTML? If its a former which version of MS Word implements it?

Thank you for any pointers you can provide.

Comment: *"It's been suggested that since Java 1.8 has been rewritten to use HTML5"* can you please clarify this? Any source? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Stijn, one of our developer made a comment during the meeting that Java 1.8 is HTML5 compliant and since our code is not been tested ever with/against HTML5 we think that the bug I described might be related.

Comment: As far as I know, Word puts information on the Clipboard in its "native" (X)HTML format - the "round-trip" HTML that completely describes a Word document. This round-trip HTML is undocumented and what Word actually writes (using a converter) is likely adjusted with each new version of Word in order to take new functionality into account. But no idea which version of HTML is used. (BTW there is no Word 2012 version.)